# Onchange doesn't work in second time

Tags: javascript

I people, i have a problem here.

I have two functions that copy values between collections of input boxes after two options are selected in two select boxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    vetorCopiar = new Array();
    function copiar() {
        //alert("Entrei");
        formulario = document.getElementById("preferencias");
        copiar = document.getElementById("copiar").value;
        //alert("Entrei");
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var j = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].name.indexOf(copiar+'_') == 0) {
                //copiar[i] = inputs[i].name.indexOf(copiar+'_').value;
                vetorCopiar[j] = inputs[i].value;
                j++;
           }
        }
        return;
    }

    function colar() {
        colar = document.getElementById("colar").value;

        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var j = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if(inputs[i].name.indexOf(colar+'_') == 0) {
                document.getElementById(inputs[i].name).value=vetorCopiar[j];
                //alert(document.getElementById(inputs[i].name).value);
                //alert(vetorCopiar[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("copiar").value = "";
        document.getElementById("colar").value = "";
        vetorCopiar = null;
        return;
    }
</script>

<p>Copiar valor de <span>
    <select name="copiar" id="copiar" onchange="copiar();">
        <option selected="selected">Dia a copiar</option>
        <option value="segunda">Segunda</option>
        <option value="terca">Terça</option>
        <option value="quarta">Quarta</option>
        <option value="quinta">Quinta</option>
        <option value="sexta">Sexta</option>
        <option value="sabado">Sabado</option>
        <option value="domingo">Domingo</option>
    </select>
     para 
    <select name="colar" id="colar" onchange="colar();">
        <option selected="selected">Dia a colar</option>
        <option value="segunda">Segunda</option>
        <option value="terca">Terça</option>
        <option value="quarta">Quarta</option>
        <option value="quinta">Quinta</option>
        <option value="sexta">Sexta</option>
        <option value="sabado">Sabado</option>
        <option value="domingo">Domingo</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

In the first time this work perfectly. The problem is in the second time it doesn't work. Some help please.

Comment: What are the document.getElementById("copiar").value = ""; and document.getElementById("colar").value = ""; supposed to do? .. Looks to me that that's where you have your issue. If you remove those lines what happens then?

Comment: The same thing, if I remove this two lines the result is the same. this two line only serve to put the select box empty.